# how can I create a separate class to handle android common tasks such as creating progress dialog?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, static

I am a newbie and I am writing a simple Android app which has several Activities. In each Activity I have to use Progress Dialogs and custom layout Toasts. Also I have to save and load Preferences in some of them.
How can I put all these methods in a separate class, I don't want to write the same code in every activity. Can it be a static class?

Thank you.

```
    private void createCustomToast(String msg, String status) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View toastRoot = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_two_lines, null);
    TextView text = (TextView) toastRoot.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
    TextView textTriageStatus = (TextView) toastRoot
            .findViewById(R.id.status);
    textTriageStatus.setText(status);
    text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    text.setText(msg);
    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setView(toastRoot);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}

private void savePreferences(String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
            "APP_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private String loadPreferences(String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
            "APP_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
    return strSavedMem1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another class to handle this kind of scenario but you have to pass context to that method because toast and prefernces are handled by context. Context will many types 1)Application 2)Activity 3)Service 4)Broadcast Receiver.

```
> >  public static void createCustomToast(Context context,String msg, String status) {
>     >     LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
>     >     View toastRoot = inflater
>     >             .inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_two_lines, null);
>     >     TextView text = (TextView) toastRoot.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
>     >     TextView textTriageStatus = (TextView) toastRoot
>     >             .findViewById(R.id.status);
>     >     textTriageStatus.setText(status);
>     >     text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
>     >     text.setText(msg);
>     >     Toast toast = new Toast(context);
>     >     toast.setView(toastRoot);
>     >     toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
>     >     toast.show(); }
>     > 
>     > public static void savePreferences(Context context,String key, int value) {
>     >     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
>     >             "APP_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
>     >     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
>     >     editor.putInt(key, value);
>     >     editor.commit(); }
>     > 
>     > public void String loadPreferences(Context context,,String key) {
>     >     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
>     >             "APP_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
>     >     String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
>     >     return strSavedMem1; }
>     > 
>     > > Blockquote
```